# How to count a nested query in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, count, entity

I am trying to count the number of login failures per day using springboot.Thus far i have discovered that there is countBy which can be used to count however i am not sure how to perform this query using countBy.

This is what i want to do:

```
count all login attempts where date = today'sDate , 
                         loginID = userLoginID 
                         and booleanLoginSuccess = false
```

This is what i attempted in my LoginRepository :

```
Long countByTodayDateAndLoginCredentialsIDAndloginSuccessStatusTrue( String currentDate, int loginId);
```

This is the error i got :

```
  No property loginCredentialsIDAndloginSuccessStatus found for type LoginInformation!
```

**This is my LoginInformation Entity :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LoginInformation")
public class LoginInformation {

    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int loginID;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Boolean loginSuccessStatus;
    private String deviceID;
    private String appVersion;
    private String deviceOS;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String todayDate;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="loginCredentialsID")
    private UserLogin userLogin;

public LoginInformation() {
}

public LoginInformation(Boolean loginSuccessStatus, String deviceID, String appVersion, String deviceOS) {
    this.loginSuccessStatus = loginSuccessStatus;
    this.deviceID = deviceID;
    this.appVersion = appVersion;
    this.deviceOS = deviceOS;
}

public LoginInformation(Boolean loginSuccessStatus, String deviceID, String appVersion, String deviceOS, String todayDate, UserLogin userLogin) {
    this.loginSuccessStatus = loginSuccessStatus;
    this.deviceID = deviceID;
    this.appVersion = appVersion;
    this.deviceOS = deviceOS;
    this.todayDate = todayDate;
    this.userLogin = userLogin;
}

    ... omitted getter and setters for brevity
```

**This is my UserLogin Entity :**

```
Entity
@Table(name = "UserLogin",
uniqueConstraints = 
          {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "userName")
        })
public class UserLogin implements Serializable, UserDetails  {
    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int loginCredentialsID;

    private String username;
    private String password;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userLogin", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<LoginInformation> loginInfo = new ArrayList();


    public UserLogin(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }


    public UserLogin() {
    }
... omitted getter and setters for brevity
```

Comment: Please post your `LoginInformation` entity code. And btw, just because you can use methods with horrendously long names, doesn't mean you should do that to yourself and future unfortunate code readers

Comment: i have added the LoginInfomation Entity and my apologies for the long names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity fields should be used, not column names.

```
Long countByTodayDateAndUserLoginLoginCredentialsIDAndloginSuccessStatusTrue( String currentDate, int loginId);
```

userLogin is Object so, to access its id add Id in method name

Comment: i get the following error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type

Comment: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [usermanagementapi.Entities.UserLogin (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [usermanagementapi.Entities.UserLogin (n/a)]"

Comment: i think your answer is correct but the do u have any idea on how to solve the parameter missmatch issue

Comment: I think the reason is your id is named loginCredentialsID.